# Django - value too long for type character varying (but appears to be within max_length limit)

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm getting a really strange database error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(4)
```

This occurs when I'm trying to save a `Question` in my survey app. The odd thing is: I believe I am only trying to save 4 chars to that field!

The `.save(update_fields=['question_type', 'question_text', 'quota'])` call passes ModelForm validation, so I went to my db to see if it actually matched the model, and it does:

```
db=# \d surveyapp_question;
       Table "public.surveyapp_question"
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
---------------+------------------------+-----------
 uuid          | uuid                   | not null
 question_type | character varying(4)   | not null
 question_text | character varying(255) | 
 order         | integer                | 
 quota         | smallint               |
```

As you can see, there's only one `varchar(4)` in the model: `question_type`. The value I'm trying to save to that column is "`text`". The POST data shows "text". If I put a `print(form.cleaned_data['question_type']` in `form_valid` it also shows `text`.

So I looked at the postgres log:

```
tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
...
UPDATE "surveyapp_question" SET "question_type" = '(''text'',)' WHERE...
```

Sooo ... that doesn't look right? What's with the "`''text''`"? Why don't I have `"text"` in that tuple? Is that what's causing the error?

I'm running django 1.10, psycopg2 2.6.2 and PostgreSQL 9.4.7.

Comment: Can you post your form, view and model?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that Timmy - it's only when I was sanitizing the `view` for public viewing that I noticed a line had a trailing comma appended on a line that was setting a property of `self`. How on earth that gets translated into dodgy SQL is beyond me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when doing:

```
self.question.some_property = form.cleaned_data['some_property'],
```

I appended a trailing comma by accident, and that didn't raise a syntax error for my particular code somehow, but went right through psycopg2 to the database as a dodgy query. That's probably a really obscure error that won't happen to anyone else, but I'll leave the question up in case the debugging procedure is useful for folks.

Comment: Just FYI, `form.cleaned_data['...']` is a string so putting the `,` after it creates a a tuple to your form field (and model). Try `s = "hello",` in your interpreter and you'll see what I mean. This tuple is then being cast back into a string to be saved to your DB

Comment: Wow, thanks for that explanation! I didn't realise you could declare a tuple without the parenthesis.